# int32_t and int64_t Conversion Issues

Tags: c++, type-conversion, accumulate

In the following line of code, `positive` is a vector of `int32_t` elements.

```
int32_t pos_accum = accumulate(positive.begin(), positive.end(), std::multiplies<int32_t>());
```

The compiler generates the following error that seems to make no sense:

```
No suitable conversion function from "std::multiplies<int32_t>" to "int32_t" exists
```

as well as

```
'initializing': cannot convert from '_Ty' to 'int32_t'
```

The ultimate goal is to store the answer in an `int64_t`, but attempts to `static_cast<int64_t>` the result ends up in similar errors.

Any idea what the problem is here?

Comment: Re: "The ultimate goal is to store the answer in an int64_t", you can control the result type of the accumulation by changing the type of the `init` argument. In your case passing  `std::int64_t{1}` for `init` would do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) that accepts a binary operator is

```
template< class InputIt, class T, class BinaryOperation >
constexpr T accumulate( InputIt first, InputIt last, T init, BinaryOperation op );
```

You're missing the `init` argument, which represents the initial value of the accumulation. Try

```
accumulate(positive.begin(), positive.end(), 1, std::multiplies<int32_t>());
```

Comment: Don't make me quote Yoda, man. Don't make me do it.

Comment: Of course!  Thank you!